# Can someone help me solve this with a simple subquery in the where clause?

Tags: mysql, subquery, logical-operators

Discription: We want to look at some patterns of customer buying habits for specific months. 
We are concerned about book sales to customers in a three month period starting 6 months ago and extending for two months.

I need help with this problem- **Problem: Display customer id and name for all customers who have purchases in exactly one of the months of the three months under discussion. For example, the customer might have a purchase in the second month but not in the first or third month.**

Answer to similar problem: Display customer id and name for all customers who have no purchases in any month under discussion.

```
set @rundate = current_date;
set @Mnth_1 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
set @Mnth_2 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 5 MONTH);
set @Mnth_3 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 4 MONTH);
Select Distinct c_id, c_name
From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
Where order_id Not IN (
    Select order_id
    From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
    Where Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_1, '%M %Y'))
and order_id Not IN (
    Select order_id
    From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
    Where Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_2, '%M %Y'))
and order_id Not IN (
    Select order_id
    From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
    Where Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_3, '%M %Y'));
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question , with example if needed plz?

Comment: We are concerned about book sales to customers in a three month peri
od starting 6 months ago and extending
for two months. I have the answer to a similar problem. Here is the problem:

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this i'm not sure but may work for you.

```
set @rundate = current_date;
set @Mnth_1 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
set @Mnth_2 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 5 MONTH);
set @Mnth_3 = DATE_SUB(@rundate,  INTERVAL 4 MONTH);
Select Distinct c_id, c_name
From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
Where order_id Not IN (
    Select order_id
    From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
    Where Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_1, '%M %Y') and Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_2, '%M %Y') and Date_format(order_date, '%M %Y') = Date_format(@Mnth_3, '%M %Y') )
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you need a period you may use `BETWEEN` construction. Also i think it is better to use `AND NOT EXISTS` then `NOT IN`.

```
Select Distinct c_id, c_name
From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
Where order_id NOT IN (
 Select order_id
 From a_bkorders.bkv_CustOrders
 Where order_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
)
```